# Stripe card not storing, but customer is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I am able to save a new customer into my web app, but I am unable to give that customer a credit card.  I believe that I am following the instructions from stripe.com correctly, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I am using ruby/rails and haml

My code is below

**payment.html.haml:**

```
= form_tag("", method: "POST", id: "payment-form") do
    %span.payment-errors
    .field
        = label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number", class: "labelTag"
        = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, {:class => "ss-form-control", :name => nil, "data-stripe" => "number"}
    .field
        = label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVC)", class: "labelTag"
        = text_field_tag :card_code, nil, {:class => "ss-form-control minilabel", :name => nil, "data-stripe" => "cvc"}
    .field
        = label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration", class: "labelTag"
        = select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month", class: 'minilabel', "data-stripe" => 'exp-month'}
        = select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year", "data-stripe" => 'exp-year'}
    %button.standardButton.btn.btn-sumbit{type: "submit"} Submit Payment
```

**application.js**

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('mykey');
$('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    alert('first')
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
});
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    alert('second');
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
# Get the credit card details submitted by the form
token = params[:stripeToken]

# Create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :card => token,
      :description => current_user.email
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the params that are being submitted? This would help to see if the token is even being submitted via the form.

Comment: @MartinLang this is all the code that I have.  I am new to ruby/rails, so how would a pass params?

Comment: No worries - Here to help. - When you submit the form, your terminal should show the params you are submitting on the request. Params are mor or less the 'body' of the request. In your code, you are calling token = params[:stripeToken], which means you are trying to fetch the stripeToken from the params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to say where an error here without seeing Rails log on post form but I suppose that this is because you just don't specify a path in form_tag. i.e.

```
= form_tag("", method: "POST", id: "payment-form")
```

instead of

```
= form_tag("/some_path", method: "POST", id: "payment-form")
```

or

```
= form_tag(some_path, method: "POST", id: "payment-form")
```